# ldapsearch: possible to include user attributes in the output/result even if the attribute is not set or null?

Tags: linux, ldap, ldap-query

Dear stackoverflow community,
time to ask my first (and maybe stupid) question here :)

I am facing the following problem at the moment and hope that maybe some of you can help me with this:
for reasons, I have to query our Active-Directory to get some user data and write it into an CSV file on my Linux machine. For the query, I use the `ldapsearch` utility. Basically I was able to get this to work and query the user attributes i need. Now I'm facing the problem, that I have some users, that dont have one or more of the queried attributes set (e.g. "othertelephone"). In this case, ldapsearch does not include these empty attribute(s) in the output/result.
Is there a possibility to include all queried attributes in the result/output, even if they are not set or empty? The reasons I need this, is to keep a uniform clean format of the output (to convert the output into CSV easily later on). So e.g. if Attribute "othertelephone" is empty, I want to have the output looks like that:

```
sn: abc
givenName: xyz
othertelephone: 
memberOf: blablabla
```

instead of

```
sn: abc
givenName: xyz
memberOf: blablabla
```

Sadly, I have not found any switch of the `ldapsearch` command with which I can achieve this. Is this even possible with `ldapsearch` or which other way can i go? I am thankful for every hint you can give to a beginner.

Comment: I don't think you can ... you can, however, use e.g. `awk` to massage the ldif data into shape.  [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=3025188#post3025188) may get you started on the **how** ...

Comment: So ... did you have a look at the script in the link? If you have questions regarding it I'm happy to answer them here.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with me. I already work with awk in my actual script, but only to form given data not handle missing data/attributes. Unfortunatly i had no time the last week to check it in detail, but it looks like this script will help me. I will check and test it this week and if any question will come up, I'll come back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: @tink I have tested the script from the link and encountered the following Problem: i defined 10 attributes/list items. Following will happen, if i pass my ldapsearch output to the script: if a user has one or more missing attributes (because the value is empty), the script set the value of the attribute to the value of the last user which has this attribute set, instead of just printing "" for an empty attribute in the awk output.

Comment: @tink another question i have is, on which point in the script are the leading and trailing "" ot the values are set? i want to get rid of them, because i need the output look like `value,value,value` instead of `"value","value","value"`. I know i can get rid of them by piping the awk output to `tr -d \"` but it would be much better if i can avoid setting them directly in the awk script. Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: Can you throw your modified version in a pastebin somewhere and post the link here?  Happy to go over it with you, but troubleshooting in chat here is cumbersome.

Comment: Anyway, the "quotes" happen here (two statements): `printf( "\"%s\",", res[list[j]])` ... just change that to: `printf( "%s,", res[list[j]])` ...

Comment: @tink I have now pasted the modified script here on pastebin.com [here](https://pastebin.com/Zv4UxjEn). I've modified the following lines: 8-17 (attributes; i replaced the real attribute names in the pastebin); 28 (added this line to remove lines containing the DN in LDIF output); 29+42 (commented, because i dont have a matching pattern in my output. All has the same objectClass);  38 (changed value for j<= regarding my amount of attributes); 39 (changed comma to semicolon); 41 (changed index of list[] regarding amount of my attributes). I appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you please also paste some anonymised ldif data, and ideally some expected output?  I think I can see how/why the "creep" between entities happens ... but I'd like to test that.

Comment: @tink here i have the example ldif, the output of the awk script and the expected output, how it should looks like: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/5PauZ1d2)

Comment: @tink i came back to ask if you was able to test your supposition. I still was not able to find out the point of failure (i really dont understand this awk scripting things to be honest). I would appreciate very much :)

Comment: Ooops ... sorry, got distracted back then and then forgot. Can you please paste your current script, a few lines of sample data and desired output somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no ldapsearch utilities that will return empty values.

However you can use [Apache Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) and do the search and then copy table (icon in upper right) then pasting into text editor and achieve almost the same result.

Comment: Thank you for sharing - never heared about Apache Studio before. But i think this is no valid option for me, because i need query the AD, transform the output format and write it into a CSV in an automated process/script scheduled on my linux server (no GUI).